# Is there a way to have a "jupyter notebook template"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want a file with the following properties:

- Contains the code + markdown in a jupyter notebook
- Is not runnable -- can be safely checked in to a VC system

My use case is I want to have a notebook template for computing various stats on some sims I'm running. For each sim, I want to be able to

- papermill or nbconvert into a sim report using this template
- create an actual jupyter notebook (just for that sim) from this template (for an interesting stat in this template report, I can drill down)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [JupyText](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) to make a notebook in an alternate format and then you can make a [Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) project with things the way you like..

I'm not using Jupytext in my Cookiecutter.. but here is an example cookiecutter project I made.

https://gitlab.com/usmcamp0811/cronus